# Reinstalling the 14.10 standard kernel

Tags: kernel, 14.10

I tampered a bit with the 3.18 kernel and would like to go back to the standard out of the box kernel of 14.10.

How can I do this in a proper way? I executed already

```
   sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-headers-generic linux-image-generic
   sudo update-grub
```

am I now back on the mainstream kernel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default your higher numbered 3.18 kernel will still be loaded by grub during boot. There are a few options: Just make grub visible and with a longer timeout, so that you can select which kernel you want (suggested for people that often try different kernels); modify grub to select the "out of the box" kernel by default (suggested if you want to keep the 3.18 kernel); delete any newer test kernels so that the "out of the box" one becomes the highest numbered one and therefore the default.

I'll expand on the third option (the 3.18 kernel can always be re-installed again, if desired in future):

Boot into a kernel that you will not be deleting.
list all the kernels and headers:

```
dpkg -l | grep linux-
```

manually delete the higher numbered test kernels. You can and paste from the above listing. Example:

```
doug@s15:~$ uname -a
Linux s15 3.13.0-45-generic #74-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jan 13 19:36:28 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

doug@s15:~$ dpkg -l | grep linux-
ii  linux-firmware    1.127.11  all Firmware for Linux kernel drivers
...
ii  linux-headers-3.19.0-rc3-250  3.19.0-rc3-250-188 amd64 Linux kernel headers for 3.19.0-rc3-250 on amd64
ii  linux-headers-3.19.0-rc5-250  3.19.0-rc5-250-189 amd64 Linux kernel headers for 3.19.0-rc5-250 on amd64
...
ii  linux-image-3.19.0-rc3-250  3.19.0-rc3-250-188  amd64 Linux kernel, version 3.19.0-rc3-250
ii  linux-image-3.19.0-rc5-250  3.19.0-rc5-250-189  amd64 Linux kernel, version 3.19.0-rc5-250
...

doug@s15:~$ sudo dpkg -r linux-headers-3.19.0-rc3-250
(Reading database ... 230997 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-headers-3.19.0-rc3-250 (3.19.0-rc3-250-188) ...

doug@s15:~$ sudo dpkg -P linux-image-3.19.0-rc3-250
(Reading database ... 211869 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-image-3.19.0-rc3-250 (3.19.0-rc3-250-188) ...
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-rc3-250
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-rc5-250
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-rc5-250
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-45-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-45-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-44-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-44-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-43-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-43-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /memtest86+.elf
Found memtest86+ image: /memtest86+.bin
Found Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (14.04) on /dev/sdb5
done
Purging configuration files for linux-image-3.19.0-rc3-250 (3.19.0-rc3-250-188) ...
```

Note: you might have more headers and images to remove per kernel, depending on where they are from.

Comment: Thanks. I figured out to switch to the older kernels and delete the 3.18 kernel that was not the problem. But am I really now back on stock again with `sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-headers-generic linux-image-generic` I'm on `3.16.0-30-generic` how do I know this was the stock kernel of 14.10?

Comment: Use the [packages](http://packages.ubuntu.com/) web site to manually confirm version numbers of any package for any version of Ubuntu. For Utopic, I get 3.16.0.29.30 for both linux-image-generic and linux-headers-generic.

Comment: Ok I've got 3.16.0.30.31 how do I properly get back to the stock version so that I'm part of the normal update process again?

Comment: Sorry, including [updates](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=linux-image-generic&searchon=names&suite=utopic-updates&section=all), 3.16.0.30.31 is the latest and you should be O.K. and part of the normal update process again.

Comment: Ah ok so `utopic-updates` is the correct package list to look for. thx